# Reading the Directory table of an MSI with a custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.8, dtf

I have a managed code custom action which uses the following code to read a custom table.

```
var Configfolder = session.Database.OpenView(session.Database.Tables["ProtectedConfigFolders"].SqlSelectString);
```

This works how ever when I try and read the directory table in the same way

```
var dirview = session.Database.OpenView(session.Database.Tables["Directory"].SqlSelectString);
```

I get

> exception of type
>   'Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.BadQuerySyntaxException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll.

Answer (score 0):

If your custom action is executed after CostFinalize you can reference the Directory table values by just just treating them like MSI properties (i.e. grab a directory the same way you would grab "ProductVersion" or "ProductName" in a custom action).

Comment: I ended up doing that as I had to finish the product. But I really wanted to read the table to get the parent directory in the end I just used the Directory.GetParent method however found it odd that I couldn't read that table and wondered if maybe it was a bug in DTF as i could also read the file table and component table in the same way with no problems. However I could find no other reference to this problem. I will wait and if no one comes up with the answer by tomorrow I will  mark your answer. Although it doesn't answer my question is was the solution i used and is technically correct.